# Highcharts: minorTickInterval doesn't work with specified categories

Tags: highcharts

Here is a sample with specified categories: http://jsfiddle.net/galex/Fj25C/3/
If categories option is commented then minorTickInterval works well.
Is it Highcharts bug or is something wrong in options?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickInterval:1,
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            categories: ["cat1","cat2","cat3","cat4","cat5"]
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [stated in the API that](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minorTickInterval) (bolding mine):

> minorTickInterval: Number
>
> Tick interval in scale units for the minor
>   ticks. On a linear axis, if "auto", the minor tick interval is
>   calculated as a fifth of the tickInterval. If null, minor ticks are
>   not shown.
>
> On logarithmic axes, the unit is the power of the value. For example,
>   setting the minorTickInterval to 1 puts one tick on each of 0.1, 1,
>   10, 100 etc. Setting the minorTickInterval to 0.1 produces 9 ticks
>   between 1 and 10, 10 and 100 etc. A minorTickInterval of "auto" on a
>   log axis results in a best guess, attempting to enter approximately 5
>   minor ticks between each major tick.
>
> **On axes using categories, minor ticks are not supported.**
>
> Try it: Null by default, "auto" on linear Y axis, 5 units on linear Y
>   axis, "auto" on logarithmic Y axis, 0.1 on logarithmic Y axis.

Comment: Yes, it is there now. I seen old version of the documentation... Thanks.

Comment: Well I just wasted an hour on this.